# Odata supported endpoint cannot output count?

Tags: c#, .net, count, controller, odata

I am currently having an API endpoint, which using EF fetches data from the database as such:

Controller:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The View Controller Class
    /// </summary>
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    [Route(ApiEndpointConfiguration.External)]
    public class ViewController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IViewService viewService;
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly IUserContext userContext;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs ViewController
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="viewService">IViewService</param>
        /// <param name="userContext">IUserContext</param>
        /// <param name="loggerFactory">ILoggerFactory</param>
        /// <param name="options">LoggerOptions</param>
        public ViewController(
            IViewService viewService,
            IUserContext userContext,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            LoggerOptions options)
        {
            this.userContext = userContext;
            this.viewService = viewService;
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateSystemLogger<ViewController>("Log", options);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve TableViews you can view
        /// OData is enabled to allow for building queries
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>TableView</returns>
        /// <response code="200">TableView</response>
        /// <response code="401">Unauthorized</response>
        /// <response code="403">Forbidden</response>
        /// <response code="404">Not Found</response>
        /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery()]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            logger.Information($"A GET request was performed by {HttpContext.Connection.Id}");
            var userIdParameter = HttpContext.Request.Query["userId"];
            Guid userId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIdParameter) ? userContext.UserId : Guid.Parse(userIdParameter);
            bool isAllowed = userContext.CanExecute("AdminView");
            if (!isAllowed && userContext.UserId != userId)
            {
                throw new InvalidPermissionsException(userContext.UserId,
                    "User does not have permission to get the view");
            }

            var views = viewService
                .Get()
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId || x.UserId == null)
                .ToList();

            return Ok(views.ToViewModel());
        }
```

I am able to filter the result using url as

```
https://localhost:5001/external/api/View?$filter=targetSystem%20eq%20%27frontpage%27%20and%20targetName%20eq%20%27car%27
```

But when I add count I don't see the count value anywhere?
why?

```
https://localhost:5001/external/api/View?$filter=targetSystem%20eq%20%27frontpage%27%20and%20targetName%20eq%20%27car%27&$count=true
```

in my startup.cs I have configured it as such

```
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter();
        });
```

so count should be included? why is it not being parsed in my output?

I am interested in knowing the sql generated by odata when count is being queried, but it seems like count does not respond at all..

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample OData request and response using count:

Request

```
https://localhost:5000/api/v1/HomepageBanner?%24filter=id%20eq%202&%24count=true
```

Response body

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5000/api/v1/$metadata#HomepageBanner",
  "@odata.count": 0,
  "value": []
}
```

As you can see from the response, the one you are looking at is `"@odata.count"`

Edit:
To be honest, I can't see why you could filter but can't get the count, you could do filter means that the OData endpoint was working.

Maybe you could compare your solution with what I'm doing on my github repo?
https://github.com/martinussuherman/odata-test

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer?